# Questions are highlighted in blue

Tags: discussion

This may just fall under the "I haven't been paying attention to the other sites" category, but why are some questions highlighed in blue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is highlighting questions with tags that are in your favorite tags.  If you haven't manually added any favorite tags, the system will detect when you have a certain level of activity in a tag and infer one for you.  If you manually add a favorite tag, the system will not infer a tag for you.

You can customize your favorite (and ignored tags) in [your profile](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/28/steves?tab=prefs).  You can also customize these settings in the right sidebar of the homepage and the /questions listing.

So, if you would prefer not to have any questions highlighted, you can simply add a nonsense "tag" to your favorites.  Perhaps [unicorn](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorn)? (:

Comment: That fixed it.  Kind of a silly way it does that automatically, I think.  A notification banner would be nice.

Comment: A note, this didnt work in IE8, but does now in IE9... And, `[unicorn]` is not nonsense!

Comment: @AviD Moar 'corn! Kthxbye

Answer (score 2):

Am on my mobile right now so can't do a full check, but does this question on meta.so answer your query?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22184/154443

Generally meta questions which will be generic across the entire SE network will go in there.

Comment: Well, maybe.  If the blue is equivalent to creme, the questions have tags that I've set as interesting to me.  Except that I haven't set any as interesting.